# Identify scale name using Scala

Tags: scales

Does the program Scala (http://www.huygens-fokker.org/scala/) provide the ability to identify (i.e. name) a scale given its intervals or tones? Can't find the documentation to perform this operation.

Comment: I am by no means an expert on Scala but I would say _no_. That is beyond the scope of the software. The closest you can get is probably the "SHOW DATA" command.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to name *scales* or *tunings*? Scala has a very large database of *tunings* with names attached that can help with identification. If you're looking at a *scale* like 1 b2 3 4 b5 6 7 9 (or C Db E F Gb A B etc) and want to know whether it has a traditional name, that's a different question (which Scala indeed can't help you with, but I can a bit).

Comment: Thanks @helveticat yes, Scala is kind of confusing (to me at least) as to what it considers a tuning vs a scale. My intent is to identify scales.

Comment: Aha, then you might find this useful: https://archive.org/details/ScaleAndArpeggioResourcesAGuitarEncyclopedia. It's guitar-centric but contains a lot of scales with names. They're mostly based on the Carnatic system since Western music doesn't have set names for most "synthetic" scales. Disclaimer: I'm the author. There are a lot of other "scale dictionaries" around as well, and I take issue in the book with some of the traditional naming conventions, so do look around at other sources of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, Scala can identify scales.**

From the [Scala website "Features" section](http://www.huygens-fokker.org/scala/#features):

> **Recognises more than 2900 musical modes**. You can check any scale to see if it approximates an existing mode. (Bold original)